# python script for validating files in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, pydev, syntax-checking

I have a self defined text editable (datafile) file format (which uses certain python types as dict, tuples, lists etc as well) for providing arguments data to my python scripts. These arguments are later used in my Main python script.

Currently, at the start of Main program, I am consolidating (using os.walk) all such datafiles and parsing them every time which takes a lot of time. 
This is my issue!

Is there a mechanism in eclipse to run a python script (independent like a parser) and use above "datafile" as argument to check for syntax errors immediately after I **save the file.** So that I will not bother to check for syntax errors while running Main program.

Is this possible?

I am using Eclipse IDE with pydev for my development work.

Regards,

Comment: You can add an Ant based builder to the project which can run your code: see the Eclipse help on [Ant & external tools tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-80_ant.htm&cp=0_1_2)

Comment: Appreciate your inputs greg, thanks. Will take a look